# add new words to GoogleNews by gensim

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim, google-news

I want to get word embeddings for the words in a corpus. I decide to use pretrained word vectors in *GoogleNews* by *gensim* library. But my corpus contains some words that are not in GoogleNews words. for these missing words, I want to use arithmatic mean of n most similar words to it in GoggoleNews words. First I load GoogleNews and check that the word "to" is in it?

```
#Load GoogleNews pretrained word2vec model
model=word2vec.KeyedVectors.Load_word2vec_format("GoogleNews-vectors-negative33.bin",binary=True)
print(model["to"])
```

I receive an error: `keyError: "word 'to' not in vocabulary"`
is it possible that such a large dataset doesn't have this word? this is true also for some other common word like "a"!

For adding missing words to word2vec model,first I want to get indices of words that are in GoogleNews. for missing words I have used index 0.

```
#obtain index of words
word_to_idx=OrderedDict({w:0 for w in corpus_words})
word_to_idx=OrderedDict({w:model.wv.vocab[w].index for w in corpus_words if w in model.wv.vocab})
```

then I calculate the mean of embedding vectors of most similar words to each missing word.

```
missing_embd={}
for key,value in word_to_idx.items():
    if value==0:
        similar_words=model.wv.most_similar(key)
        similar_embeddings=[model.wv[a[0]] for a in similar_words]
        missing_embd[key]=mean(similar_embeddings)
```

And then I add these news embeddings to word2vec model by:

```
for word,embd in missing_embd.items():
    # model.wv.build_vocab(word,update=True)
    model.wv.syn0[model.wv.vocab[word].index]=embd
```

There is an un-consistency. When I print missing_embed, it's empty. As if there were not any missing words.
But when I check it by this:

```
for w in tokens_lower:
    if(w in model.wv.vocab)==False:
        print(w)
        print("***********")
```

I found a lot of missing words.
Now, I have 3 questions:
1- why ***missing_embed*** is empty while there are some missing words?
2- Is it possible that GoogleNews doesn't have words like "to"?
3- how can I append new embeddings to word2vec model? I used ***build_vocab*** and ***syn0***. Thanks.

Comment: The GoogleNews word2vec model probably excluded 'to' and 'a' due to their insignificance as stopwords. I don't think it's possible to update the model vocab since the model is generated from the C tool per the [tutorial](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/) found here, but you can give it a shot with `model.build_vocab(sentences, update=True)`.

Comment: you mean that after loading moldel I use model.build_vocab(sentences,update=True)? and now what are the embedding vectors for missing word?

Comment: Yes, you can try that, but again, I don't think its possible since Google's word2vec model was built with the C toolkit. You won't be able to get any similar embeddings for missing words since the model vocab never had these words to train on.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  But when I use `model.build_vocab`  I get this error: `AttributeError: 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'build_vocab'. How can I use build_vocab?

Comment: Hmmm try this instead: `model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative33.bin', binary=True)`. If you manage to get `build_vocab` to work afterwards, you would still have to do additional training using `model.train(sentences)`

Comment: but when I don't use of `KeyedVectors.load`, I receive this error: `raise DeprecationWarning("Deprecated. Use gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.")
DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format instead.`

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I can't really help you then given the API change, but my gut feeling tells me that you wouldn't be able to update the model anyways even if you manage to get `build_vocab` to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a scenario where we are adding a missing lower case word.

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
path = '../input/embeddings/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
embedding = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(path, binary=True)

'Quoran' in embedding.vocab
 Output : True

'quoran' in embedding.vocab
 Output : False
```

Here Quoran is present but quoran in lower case is missing

```
# add quoran in lower case
embedding.add('quoran',embedding.get_vector('Quoran'),replace=False)

'quoran' in embedding.vocab
 Output : True
```

Comment: How can one make these changes to the word embedding persist?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible Google removed common filler words like 'to' and 'a'. If the file seems otherwise uncorrupt, and checking other words after `load()` shows that they are present, it'd be reasonable to assume Google discarded the overly-common words as having such diffuse meaning as to be of low-value.

It's unclear and muddled what you're trying to do. You assign to `word_to_idx` twice - so only the second line matters.

(The first assignment, creating a dict where all words have a `0` value, has no lingering effect after the 2nd line creates an all-new dict, with only entries where `w in model.wv.vocab`. The only possible entry with a `0` after this step would be whatever word in the word-vectors set was already in position `0` – if and only if that word was also in your `corpus_words`.)

You seem to want to build new vectors for unknown words based on an average of similar words. However, the `most_similar()` only works for known-words. It will error if tried on a completely unknown word. So that approach can't work.

And a deeper problem is the `gensim` `KeyedVectors` class doesn't have support for dynamically adding new word->vector entries. You would have to dig into its source code and, to add one or a batch of new vectors, modify a bunch of its internal properties (including its `vectors` array, `vocab` dict, and `index2entity` list) in a self-consistent manner to have new entries.

Comment: Now I think that I don't need to append new words to GoogleNews. Because my goal is to obtain a word embedding vector for each of the words in my corpus. I can use GoogleNews word embeddings for known words. For missing words I can use a random initialized vector with the same length to GoogleNews embeddings (300). But Can you guide me what is the best solution to generate initialized word embedding vectors?

Comment: If you have a good-sized corpus, train your own embeddings! There's nothing magical about the `GoogleNews` set, and if your problem domain *isn't* the same sort of news-articles it was trained on, your native embeddings might be better. If you have a good training corpus but still need to bootstrap word-vectors for later words out-of-vocabulary (OOV), consider using something like Facebook's FastText, a advanced word2vec variant that can approximate vectors for new words by composing subword vectors learned from the original corpus.

Comment: Such FastText OOV-generated-vectors are quite rough – but better than random, and perhaps quite good for typos and word-form-variants, in languages where such word-structure/word-roots provide strong hints as to meaning. Facebook has also released pre-trained FastText vectors (https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md), analogous to GoogleNews though only trained on Wikipedia, for many languages.

Comment: Do you know the range to initialize the vectors? I read that just initializating randomly the vectors is enough to give the word a valid vector. Do you know how to initialize the vectors for a new word in GoogleNews-vectors-negative300?

Comment: @JuanPerez, these models typically initialize word-vectors to low-magnitude random positions – but then it is only via training, alongside other words from varied usage examples, that the word-vectors move to positions that are useful. (Just adding random vectors isn't helpful.) You'd have to say more about what you're trying to achieve to give a good answer – and that probably deserves a new question specific to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gojomo, I am tailoring the question to post it.